# Form is not submitting to data base from wordpress site through Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, wordpress

Following is my form which comes in the popup and i cant submit the data to the data base. please help me to solve this out

```
<div id="fsModal" class="modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
    <button type="button" id="cross-btn" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
        <div id="desk-view" class="modal-body">
            <div id="pop-up" class="row">   
                <div class="arrow_box side-heading col-xs-5 col-sm-5">
                    <h3>Join the Movement, the newsletter that tackles the justice issues that matter to you most.</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="right-form col-xs-7 col-sm-7">
                    <form id="form-search" action="" method="POST" class="form-inline subscribe-form">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input id="email-form" type="email" class="email-popup" placeholder="Enter your email" name="email">
                        </div>
                        <a href="#" id="submit-form" class="btn-form">Sign up</a>
                    </form> 
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

and my **Ajax** is  like this

```
$('#submit-form').click(function(e) {
    $.ajax({
        data: {'user_email':$("#email-form").val()},
        type: "POST",
        url: "http://localhost/womensweb-local/index.php/news-letter/",
       success: function(data){
           alert(data);
       }
   });});
```

and im directing to the template page to newsletter_insert.php to submit form.and my template php code is like this

```
$email=$_POST['email'];
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
    if (isset($_POST['user_email']) && !empty($_POST['user_email'])) {
        $wpdb->insert('newsletter_table', array(
            "emailaddress" => $email
        ));
        echo "1";
    }else{
        echo "2";
    }
}
if (data == 1) {
        alert("Subscribed Successfully!!");
    } else if(data == 2){
        alert("Something Went Error");
    }
```

Comment: What is the HTTP error you are getting?

Comment: i'm not getting any error but the form is not submitting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('#submit-form').click(function(e) {
        $.ajax({
            data:{'user_email':$("#email-form").val()},
            type: "POST",
            url: "http://localhost/xxxx/index.php/news-letter/",
            success: function(data){
                if (data == 1) {
                    alert("Subscribed Successfully!!");
                } else if(data == 2){
                    alert("Something Went Error");
                }
            }
        });
    });
```

php code is

```
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
    if (isset($_POST['user_email']) && !empty($_POST['user_email'])) {
        $wpdb->insert('newsletter-table', array(
            "emailaddress" => $_POST['user_email'],
            "date" =>  date('Y-m-d')
        ));
        echo "1";
    }else{
        echo "2";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var data = {'user_email':$("#email-form").val()};
```

use [JSON.stringify](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) to stringify data to JSON and then pass from ajax as below instead of `data: {'user_email':$("#email-form").val()},`

as well as make sure to add `contentType: "application/json"` in your ajax request

```
data: JSON.stringify(data),
```

Comment: Ohh i have missed something please find updated answer `var data = {'user_email':$("#email-form").val()};` just change dis

Comment: no, its not working  i think error is in php file which i included

Comment: had your debug hit the php code ? is dis is correct i had doubt on this `$email=$_POST['email'];` should it be  `$email=$_POST['user_email'];`?

Answer (score 0):

In wordpress prefer function.php file using wp_ajax method:
Like below:

Your jquery code from any file in the wp

```
        jQuery.ajax({
            url: "http:your_host_name/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php",  
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            data:{ 
                action: 'your_action_name',         
            },
            success : function(response){                   

                console.log(response);

            }
        });
```

In your functions.php file write:

```
add_action("wp_ajax_your_action_name", "test_function");

function test_function(){

  echo "Here";

}
```

This way ajax works in wordpress.